# Outputing Matched Capturing group in java

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regular expressions and trying to process following regular expression to udentify ordinals in given text

```
((\\d*1)st|(\\d*2)nd|(\\d*3)rd|(\\d+)th)
```

I want to capture only the number part of the text for parsing  ie. if the text is 21st then i want to capture 21 to be parsed into Integer . I know how to match on the regular expression to understand if the pattern exists and get the specific group. Is there any way I can get group that matched as output from the expression to extract the value ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI, `11th`, `12th` and `13th`. But since you are matching text, it doesn't really matter, (and the last case already covers these).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your regexp to use non-capturing groups like this:

```
(?:(\\d*)(?:st|nd|rd|th))
```

Comment: Just throw away the outer non-capturing group. You don't need to do any grouping here.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified your regex, and - importantly - I've added wildcards at each side. The first wildcard has ? to prevent greedy matching getting rid of the first digit of e.g. `21st`.

The Pattern/Matcher approach lets you extract groups.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\d*(1st|2nd|3rd|th)).*");
String input = "21st March 2013";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if(m.matches())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```